# How to get ASG name for an ec2 instance in AWS boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

After referring to boto3 documentation, using DescribeInstances() -
the closest thing i've found to ASG ID/ ASG name is requestor ID. However, Requestor ID is same for some instances which are linked with different ASGs.

what i'm planning to do with ASG details:
after getting asg details, i'll delete the ASG for the instances with low utilization. And then delete the instances.

What would be the best way to get ASG details?

Comment: `describe_auto_scaling_groups` ?

Comment: You can use CloudWatch metrics to check which ASGs are under-utilized. Not sure why do you need instance details for that? Or better, you can setup auto-scaling policies for ASG to monitor itself, and remove instances if not used.

Comment: @Paolo- we need to pass ASG group name for that, right? I'm trying to get asg name in the first place.

Comment: @Marcin- i'm writing an automation to delete underutilized ec2s across many (70+) accounts.

Comment: @KanikaSingla Then `describe_auto_scaling_groups` will give you instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Auto Scaling Group (ASG) name for an AWS EC2 instance using its ID in Python using Boto3 using `describe_auto_scaling_instances`.

See the sample code below:

```py
import boto3
instance_id = '[INSTANCE_ID]'
asg_client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
response = asg_client.describe_auto_scaling_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
asg_name = response['AutoScalingInstances'][0]['AutoScalingGroupName']
```

Where `[INSTANCE_ID]` is the AWS EC2 instance id.